# Flutter App Not Work on Mobile Phone After Release Update

Tags: flutter, release, flutter-dependencies

This is my 4th update of the Flutter Application in the Google Play Store. I have change API from 16 to 19. I have added some functions in my app that's why I need to change it because 16 not supported by dependency. When I test the app on the emulator it works fine. When I release apk bundle and update the app on Google Play Store it's not working on the user side application. It does not show any error. open smoothly.
I am using SQLite database. When I create a new record it shows me message data saved but data not appear on the application.

Sorry for the Week English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to run with release `flutter run --release` ?
you can also check play store version logs with `adb logcat`

Comment: yes i have tried, i have changed the version also

Comment: if you can share with logs or code where you interacting(read, write) with SQLite that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QpxvLZn                               here is the screenshot of logs.  SQLite is read and write perfectly in the emulator but not on the real device. and when a real device attaches as an emulator it works fine in a real device.

Comment: When I run this command "flutter build bundle --release" it shows this error    https://ibb.co/G50DW1C

Comment: try `flutter clean` and than `flutter build bundle --release`

Comment: problem with sqlite is only on Android?

Comment: problem is that , app fully work on android emulator. but not working on real device.

Comment: i have use flutter clean and then flutter build bundle --release still facing same issue